# Why is 1px sometimes 2px when specified in Android XML?

Tags: android

I've got a desire for a one-pixel divider line, just for looks.  I thought I could accomplish this using a View of height 1px, with a defined background.  However, I'm getting some very odd behavior on different devices - sometimes the 1px ends up as 2px.

Take this sample layout for example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@android:color/white" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@android:color/white" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@android:color/white" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@android:color/white" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@android:color/white" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@android:color/white" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@android:color/white" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When run on my G1, [this comes out fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU2Lp.png).  But on the Nexus One, [it alternates between 1px lines and 2px lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmOqT.png).

Does anyone know where this is going awry?  Why does Android sometimes make 1px into 2px?

Edit: To make this absolutely clear, I do not care about solving my example in particular; what I care about is being able to say "this View shall be 1px high", in any circumstance, not just this example.

Answer (score 8):

Are you building against SDK 1.5, or setting android:anyDensity="false"?  If your app does not say it supports densities, then Android will run in compatibility mode where it makes the screen look like an mdpi screen, scaling ALL coordinates and drawing to match the real screen density.  Running in an hdpi screen like Droid, this is a 1.5x scaling, so every other "pixel" will be mapped to two pixels on the screen.

Apps today should be written to support different screens, in which case the px and dp units will behave as desired on all screens.

Comment: Wow, that did it for me!  I change my min SDK from 3 to 4 and it fixed my problem.  I was seeing this symptom with my list view dividers.  Your my hero!  :)

Comment: If I want an app that runs with android:minSdkVersion="3" what can I do to not run in compatibility mode?

Comment: android:targetSdkVersion="<somethinglarger>"

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that this is occurring where the line is on the edge between pixels ; is this occuring because you are mixing dp (density-independant) pixel measurements with absolutes? If the devices have different dp / pixel ratios your margins (defined in dps) could be placing your separators on the edge between pixels.

Try changing your margins to 4px instead of 4dp.

Comment: Changing the margins to 4px instead of 4dp doesn't help (still get a mixture of 1px and 2px lines), though you may be on to something.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the question, but if you are using a ListView, you have some properties for dividers:

```
android:divider="" /*color, drawable, etc*/
android:dividerHeight="1dip"
```

Plus you really shouldn't use Pixels but independant density measurement..

Comment: You're right, this doesn't answer the question at all because I'm not asking about this for ListViews.  :P  I may ultimately use more of the implementation ListView uses for its dividers though, since they seem to remain consistent despite location.